# asp.net webforms website stopped working in IE10 but works in chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer-10

website developed in asp.net using windows authentication does not work in IE10 anymore. There was a power shutdown in data center it was hosted. The website works in chrome and it asks for credentials first time.  When I log on to server where website is hosted it works properly in IE8.

I get error: This page can't be displayed

Make sure the web address http://monitormanager.xxxx.com is correct.

Comment: Any errors in the event log on the server?

Comment: No, I do not see any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the same issue on IE11? Does it work fine with IE9? Older versions of .NET used a single-digit regular expression to identify IE versions and may therefore be identifying your browser as IE1. You can download the hotfix for .NET 4 from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088.

[Scott Hanselman wrote about this issue too.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx)

Comment: Thank you I will try and let you know

Comment: .) Open iis and select the website that is causing the 401

2.) Open the "Authentication" property under the "IIS" header

3.) Click the "Windows Authentication" item and click "Providers"

4.) For me the issue was that Negotiate was above NTLM. I assume that there was some kind of handshake going on behind the scenes, but i was never really authenticated. I moved the NTLM to the top most spot, and BAM that fixed it. This solution worked for me.